# How can a function from different python module can be used in another defined function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.6

Here I want to use the c(v) & s(v) from a module FrenselIntegral.py in a defined function f(v).

```
import FrenselIntegral as fi

v=0.0
u=0.2

def f(v): 0.5*((0.5-fi.c(v))**2+(0.5-fi.s(v))**2)

file=open("Straightedge diffraction pattern.txt","w")

for i in range (25):
   print>>file,v,f(v)
   v=v+u
file.close()
```

But, the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Shubhadeep/Desktop/New folder/Straightedge diffraction pattern.py", line 11, in <module>
    print>>file,v,f(v)
  File "c:/Users/Shubhadeep/Desktop/New folder/Straightedge diffraction pattern.py", line 4, in f
    def f(v): 0.5*((0.5-fi.c(v))**2+(0.5-fi.s(v))**2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Can you add the content of FresnelIntegral.py? It seems to me that your functions c() and s() are missing return statements.

Comment: def c(v):If v==0.0 return 0.00

Comment: So your function c() is empty for all values of v unequal to zero. Are you sure this is the full definition of c()?

Comment: No, actually def c(v): if v==0: return 0.00 elif v==0.2: return 0.37 -thus it goes so long

Comment: Can you update the question with the full content of that module? Or link it somehow? Because the content of that function seems to be the problem to me. Not the way you are importing the module

Answer (score 0):

The point looks like fi.c(v) returns None. You can check what values of v give that result or just avoid None returns, for example:

```
import FrenselIntegral as fi

v=0.0
u=0.2

def f(v):
  if fi.c(v) is None or fi.s(v) is None:
    return 0
  else:
    return 0.5*((0.5-fi.c(v))**2+(0.5-fi.s(v))**2)

file=open("Straightedge diffraction pattern.txt","w")

for i in range (25):
   print>>file,v,f(v)
   v=v+u
file.close()
```